# To convert from amount to percentage pie chart js

Tags: javascript

I have a chart but when it gets the date it just display the amount of each label without converting to percentage need help

[image]

```js
function getPieChart(rawData) {

    console.log(rawData);
    
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
       
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            startAngle: 240,
            yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
            indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
            dataPoints: rawData
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

}

getPieChart([
    { y: 444, label: "Abuja Hqrs" },
    { y: 176, label: "Kano" },
    { y: 266, label: "Alausa" },
    { y: 221, label: "Portharcourt" },
    { y: 3717, label: "Ikoyi" }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-FJ2OYvUIXUqCcPf1stu+oTBlhn54W0UisZB/TNrZaVMHHhYvLBV9jMbvJYtvDe5x/WVaoXZ6KB+Uqe5hT2vlyA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display percentages by removing `yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\""` and replacing `indexLabel: "{label} {y}"` with `indexLabel: "{label} #percent%"`.

```js
function getPieChart(rawData) { 
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
       
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            startAngle: 240,
            indexLabel: "{label} #percent%",
            dataPoints: rawData
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
}

getPieChart([
    { y: 444, label: "Abuja Hqrs" },
    { y: 176, label: "Kano" },
    { y: 266, label: "Alausa" },
    { y: 221, label: "Portharcourt" },
    { y: 3717, label: "Ikoyi" }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-FJ2OYvUIXUqCcPf1stu+oTBlhn54W0UisZB/TNrZaVMHHhYvLBV9jMbvJYtvDe5x/WVaoXZ6KB+Uqe5hT2vlyA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

See the [`indexLabel`](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/indexlabel/) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you could set format with changing properties `yValueFormatString` and `indexLabel`.

it is converted to percentage by `yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\""`. [this document](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/y-value-format-string/) might be helpful for you.

For example, if you want to describe format as `[$34]`, set `yValueFormatString: "[$##]"`

and the details for indexLabel at [here](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/indexlabel/)

See following snippet:

```js
function getPieChart(rawData) {
    
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
       
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            startAngle: 240,
            yValueFormatString: "##", // does not need
            indexLabel: "{label} is {y}",
            dataPoints: rawData
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

}

getPieChart([
    { y: 444, label: "Abuja Hqrs" },
    { y: 176, label: "Kano" },
    { y: 266, label: "Alausa" },
    { y: 221, label: "Portharcourt" },
    { y: 3717, label: "Ikoyi" }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-FJ2OYvUIXUqCcPf1stu+oTBlhn54W0UisZB/TNrZaVMHHhYvLBV9jMbvJYtvDe5x/WVaoXZ6KB+Uqe5hT2vlyA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```